# Render large point cloud set (More than 1 GB) in web browser

Tags: three.js, webgl, point-clouds

Now I am struggling in rendering point cloud in WebGL. Once the file size get larger than 200 MB, the browser will crash. I am now using Points in Three.js to render my data.

Is there any way to optimise it or good library I can use to do this case?

Comment: https://www.fossgis.de/w/images/e/e4/Potree.pdf Seems a way to solve this

Comment: What is crashing? The loading or the rendering?

Comment: @manthrax in loading phrase, I think I need to use some solution similar to streaming

Comment: I think you must include more detail about what you've done to debug the problem. This could turn out to be too much for your browser during loading, rendering, or both. If you want to compress the data (which helps loading, but not rendering), try something like [draco](https://github.com/google/draco).

Comment: What format are you loading your point cloud data in? You may need to stream or find a more optimal (binary) format, as Don McCurdy suggest.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy It is more about rendering. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very broad topic where you can do many ridiculous optimizations.

Take a look on this http://www.potree.org/

Comment: It demands points to be converted into another format where converter is not web tool rather command line tool !!